# R: Tidying and summarising a paired comparison dataset in the tidyverse style

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

I have a dataset with features {a,b,c...} belonging to a pair of players taken form the set {a, b, c}. Each row represents the outcome of a matchup, columns *name_1*, *name_2* represent player names, and all other columns **a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, etc..** represent numeric features corresponding to the player in the matchup.

Below is the example of a dataset:

```
set.seed(17)
df <- tibble(
  name_1 = sample(letters[1:3], length(letters), replace = TRUE),
  name_2 = sample(letters[1:3], length(letters), replace = TRUE),
  a1 = rnorm(length(letters)),
  a2 = rnorm(length(letters)),
  b1 = rnorm(length(letters)),
  b2 = rnorm(length(letters)),
  c1 = rnorm(length(letters)),
  c2 = rnorm(length(letters))) %>% 
  filter(!(name_1 == name_2))
```

What I need is to find a summary statistic for each feature grouped by player. The trouble is that the same player, for example, **a**, can be located sometimes under *name_1*, sometimes under *name_2*, hence his features can be located at *feature1* or *feature2*.

Here is my feeble attempt to do this for one player (namely, *a*) and one feature (namely, *a*):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(feature_a_joined = case_when(df$name_1 == "a" ~ a1,
                                      df$name_2 == "a" ~ a2)) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(feature_a_joined, na.rm = TRUE))
```

I am fairly new to R, but the examples that I`ve seen in multiple vignettes refer to more standard datasets. Is there an efficient way to make a summary for each player  and each variable?

**Update**
My expected result would be something like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  player feature_a_mean feature_b_mean feature_c_mean
  <chr>           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 a              -0.330          2.38           0.960
2 b              -0.482          1.30           0.207
3 c              -0.482         -0.477         -1.71
```

Comment: How is that updated expected output align with your code output.  I am getting a different value with your code for feature_a_joined when compared to feature_a_mean

Comment: What i meant is that you are calculating mean based on all the a, b, c (a1, a2, b1, b2, ..) for the same player which is not your initial code does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `map`.  Get the unique column names ('un1') from the data.  Loop over those (`map`), apply the OP's code with `case_when` and get the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
un1 <- unique(str_remove(names(df)[-(1:2)], "\\d+"))
map_dfc(un1, ~
       df %>%
         summarise(!! str_c('mean_', .x) :=
         mean(case_when(name_1 == .x ~ !! rlang::sym(str_c(.x, '1')), 
                        name_2 == .x ~ !! rlang::sym(str_c(.x, '2'))), 
          na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#    mean_a mean_b  mean_c
#     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 -0.00673  0.186 -0.0632
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's expected output (assuming the output values are placeholders), we reshape the multiple blocks of columns to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, do a group by to get the `summarise` `across` columns 'a' to 'c'

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c('.value', 'grp'), 
          names_sep= '(?<=[a-z])_?(?=[0-9])')  %>% 
   group_by(player = name) %>% 
   summarise(across(a:c, mean, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  player        a      b       c
#  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 a      -0.00673  0.197  0.126 
#2 b      -0.0455   0.186 -0.138 
#3 c      -0.118   -0.468 -0.0632
```

Comment: @ProwlersProfit that output is not aligning with the code you showed

Comment: those values are just placeholders. I am just trying to say that instead of a one row of feature means i need a **one row per player**

Comment: @ProwlersProfit What I am interested is from your code, it is just subsetting for corresponding 'name' ('a') with that same column name 'a1', 'a2'.  In the expected, you are showing that 'name' 'a' is also doing the mean of 'b1', 'b2', etc>